# In Selenium webdriver.switchto(), "relative=top" generates error?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm using Selenium WebDriver (v2.2) to "switch" to the "top" frame like so:

```
webdriver.SwitchTo().Frame("relative=top");
```

This generates an error message:

```
Unable to locate frame: relative=top
```

Can this be caused because the page I'm using has no frames?

EDIT

Unfortunately, both solutions that involve window switching fail:

```
webdriver.SwitchTo().Window(winHandle);
webdriver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

Strictly speaking, actually, they don't fail. But, here's the problem: Let's say I fetch an IWebElement within a frame. Here's what the code roughly looks like:

```
descend-into-the-frame
grab-the-element
ascend-out-of-the-frame-to-the-top
use-the-element
```

When I use-the-element, I get a "Element does not exist in the cache" exception. This is because the ascend-out-of-the-frame-to-the-top switches the window, which clears the cache. Quite annoying. I have figured out a workaround, though:

```
ascend-out-of-the-frame-to-the-top
descend-into-the-frame
grab-the-element
use-the-element
```

This still means I have to watch out for element-not-in-the-cache situations. But at least as long as I use an element immediately after fetching it, I'm ok.

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you Selenium IDE gave you that code when you switched from one frame to another. What I did is to store the window handle of the parent window, so that you can switch back to it later.

```
String _whandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
...
driver.switchTo().window(whandle);
driver.switchTo().frame("frameA");
driver.findElement(By.id("buttonA")).click();
driver.switchTo().window(whandle);
driver.switchTo().frame("frameB");
driver.findElement(By.id("buttonB")).click();
```

Comment: "relative=top" does not work because it is not supported by WebDriver, but Selenium RC. See http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#selectFrame(java.lang.String)

Comment: The switchTo().frame() method will direct future commands to the selected frame. That means, you have to "focus" on the selected/current frame to use the elements in that frame.

Comment: Why is it necessary driver.switchTo().window(whandle); before switching to frameA? I think, since it is at original window the code driver.switchTo().window(whandle); is redundant before driver.switchTo().frame("frameA");

Comment: That's the limitation of WebDriver. The Selenium Interface has the selectFrame() method to allow you to select the top frame with "relative=top" as the locator. But you cannot do the same with webDriver.

Answer (score 11):

To switch top frame from some other frame you can use :

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You should only SwitchTo().Frame() when the frame exists.

You can get around this with the following:

```
try
{
    webdriver.SwitchTo().Frame("relative=top");
}
catch (WebDriverException ex) 
{
    // do something, perhaps log that there is no frame
}
```

Comment: Interesting... So "relative=top" can fail? I wonder why. I mean, every window always has a "top" frame, right?

Comment: @StephenGross I don't see why not if the code is looking for an additional frame and disregards the current frame then it will never find relative=top

Comment: This is still not working for me. I have successfully traversed *into* a frame, but the switchto().frame("relative=top") mechanism still throws the exception.